# Populate VS appear

Tags: word-usage

We fill in the forms for hotel booking and the deals appear.

" Deal will appear on the screen after you fill in the form."

If I write this like "Once you fill the form, the deals will populate on your screen as per your inputs" will it be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not correct diction;  "populate" in this sense is a /transitive verb/.

This means someone or something must be "doing" the populating; they were not there before, now they are - I have populated them.

Compare with "appear" - they were not there before, now they are - They appeared.

No one has "appeared them" - because that's an intransitive verb.

You should be able to replace "place" with "populate" ('I placed/populated the deals') and 'be found' with 'appear' ('The deals will be found on your screen...')

Comment: If I say, I filled in the form and the system populated the deals on the screen, on the basis of my inputs...will that be okay?